# how to render data received from JSON in Social App with OpenSocial Templates!

Tags: templates, opensocial, json

I am getting data in the Social App in form of JSON. I am using OpenSocial v0.9 Templates to render data in the App with the tag  but the problem is I want to render data in tabular form, but with  it repeats items in a row so is there any way possible!

Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the *<os:Repeat>* tag? Maybe you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/os-template" require="mytable">
    <table>
        <os:Repeat expression="${mytable.rows}">
            <tr>
                <td>${Cur.cell1}</td>
                <td>${Cur.cell2}</td>
            </tr>
        </os:Repeat>
    </table>
 </script>
```